# Azure Cloud Service project - compiled files location before package

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013

I'm looking for a way to add external files to my Azure Cloud Service deployment. Before moving to Azure what we used to do is use xcopy in the project post build event. But that doesn't seem to work on the Azure Cloud Service project.

Is there a way I can copy external items **without including them in the project in any way**? a sort of post build that will copy to the compilation directory before it is being packaged?

What is the location of the compiled code before it is being packaged?

Comment: You need to read up on cspack to understand how the deployment package is being created and thus how you can inject files. cspack: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg432988.aspx and an example of how you can use it: https://iainhunter.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/automating-azure-1-4-packaging-using-msbuild-and-cspack/

Comment: @SimonW Thanks. If I use cspack it means that I have to upload the package manually in the azure portal?

Comment: Correct. This is just the packaging step. In order to fully deploy you will need to also have a configuration file (usually generated as well) and then provide both in order to provision a new Cloud Service.